# Como usar a função "PROCH" do Excel para buscar valores de baixo para cima?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Por padrão a função "Proch" busca somente valores de cima para baixo, eu pretendo fazer o inverso, buscar os valores de baixo para cima, quero buscar o caractere "40-D" através da referência "Cod.prod", como eu procedo através da função "Proch" ?? ou existe outra função que faça este procedimento??[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o valor que pretendes procurar e sempre o que está acima do **Cod.prod**?

Comment: Sim! tem algum modo de fazer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Elienay pegando na tabela que apresentas e para teres sempre o valor acima de Cod.prod usa a seguinte fórmula na célula **G44**.

```
=+DESLOCAMENTO(B48;-1;CORRESP(F44;C48;0);1;1)
```

## EDIÇÃO

Como podes ver a fórmula foi desenvolvida de acordo com a tua tabela inicial.

**Tabela:** C44:E48
**Valor a procurar:** F44
**Célula da fórmula:** G44

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia especificar o endereço das células de acordo com a imagem que eu postei ?? é porque eu nunca usei essa função 'deslocamento' e me deixou um pouco confuso, porque as células que vc digitou não correspondem com a tabela da imagem, poderia?

Comment: Morri tentando aqui, mas eu não descobri a solução com essa sua fórmula kkk, tenta especificar o endereço certinho, Ok?

Comment: @Elienay, a função corresponde aos dados da tua tabela. Já tentaste  copiar a fórmula e colar? Em vez de `DESLOCAMENTO` tenta `DESLOC`.

Comment: Agora que eu vi entender, minha dúvida era aquele endereço 'B48' que está sendo direcionado para uma célula vazia, pois ele funciona como referencia para as células a direita sempre buscando o valor a direita e adicionando +1 para uma célula superior.

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível, pois a lógica do PROCH é de cima para baixo, assim como o PROCV é da esquerda para a direita, sempre a partir da primeira linha, para o PROCH, ou primeira coluna, para o PROCV.

Uma solução para o seu caso é o uso do ÍNDICE + CORRESP

[image: Imagem de exemplo]

Mas se vale a pena um comentário, não faz sentido trabalhar dessa forma com os nomes das colunas em baixo. Sugiro padronizar a tabela ao invés de seguir desta forma.

Comment: Eu não consegui localizar com essa fórmula, quando eu digito "Cod.prod" ele busca o mesmo valor "Cod.prod" ele devia buscar "40-D"

Comment: Mas você não tem que digitar "cod.prod", você tem que especificar qual o código do produto que você quer procurar. No exemplo eu procurei as informações referentes ao cod.prod "40-D".

Comment: O que eu queria era buscar em sequencia, por exemplo: ao digitar "cod.prod" ele me trazia o "40-D" e se eu digitasse "40-D" ele me trazia o "30-C" e assim por diante